# Can selectable jquery ui be forced to select in order

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, selectable

I want to use jQuery's (or something similar) selectable functionality: http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#display-grid.  However, I would like to be able to force selections.

For example, for the grid, if a user starts at 1 and drags to item 6 only 1,2,5, and 6 are selected.  However, I want 3 and 4 to be selected because they are between 1 and 6 (the start and stop points).  Couldn't find any implementation of this online.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Drag and select 1-4 and then use the Ctrl to drag and select 5-6. It does it without any additional coding.